# Best Program for combining Images and Videos onto a DVD with menu

Tags: video, digital-recording, photos

I thought there would be 100 and 1 good solutions for this but so far I have not found something that could all of the following:

- Create a DVD-player DVD
- Have a menu with options
- Have images & Video
- prefrably handle .mod

Basically I am trying to put a bunch of photos and videos from our wedding & honeymoon on and older-relative friendly DVD. So it must be able to be playable in a normal dvd player so therefore it must be able to show a menu with categories.

Anyone got good recommendations for this? Everything I come across is either a completely generic menu or frankly broken!

Comment: either windows or linux programs are fine but windows would be eaiser :)

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Encore can do what you are looking for.  It is included with Adobe Premiere.  You can either buy a copy of CS6 or if you only need it for the one project, you can use Creative Cloud to obtain it for just a month or two.

In general, you will find most DVD authoring software comes in fairly expensive packages.  It's not as easy as you would think to do and not a lot of software does it.  The options now are cheap in comparison to how much it used to cost.  When I first did DVD authoring, it cost $2500 to get DVD authoring software that crashed every 15 minutes or so.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Movie Studio Platinum 12](http://vegasaur.com/SonyCreativeSoftware) (or DVD Architect Studio w/o video editor)

Comment: seems a bit overkill and expensive?